# Wrong results in Tensorflow due to GPU memory sensitivity

Tags: memory, tensorflow, gpu

Consider the following simple VGG training code in Tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
from tensorflow.contrib.slim.nets import vgg

# random input for training
images     = tf.random_normal(shape=(32, 224, 224, 3))
labels     = tf.cast(1000 * tf.random_uniform(shape=(32,)), dtype=tf.int32)

# init graph & cost
logits, _ = vgg.vgg_19(images)

cost = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cost, name='cross_entropy_loss')

# create training_op
optimizer  = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(1e-5, 0.9)
train_op   = slim.learning.create_train_op(cost, optimizer)

# start training
slim.learning.train(train_op, logdir='logs/bugreport')
```

On several of my GPUs (Tesla K40 as well as Tesla K80) the loss returns NaN pretty much right at the beginning of training (consistently on every run):

```
InvalidArgumentError: LossTensor is inf or nan : Tensor had NaN values
     [[Node: train_op/CheckNumerics = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="LossTensor is inf or nan", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](cross_entropy_loss)]]
     [[Node: train_op/control_dependency/_337 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_487_train_op/control_dependency", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Interestingly, the situation can be resolved if memory consumption is constrained to some fixed portion, i.e. by replacing the last line with

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.9)
slim.learning.train(train_op, logdir='logs/bugreport', 
                    session_config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

in which case training runs smoothly. However, increasing the memory fraction to 0.95 brings back the above error. I can reproduce this bug on some other GPUs (again K40 or K80) albeit with different thresholds (on one the memory fraction cannot go beyond 0.7), but not all GPUs are affected. Even worse, I have another example (evaluating a fixed set of 1000 images on VGG) for which the returned accuracy depends on the batch size if no memory constraints are applied.

The variation between GPUs suggests that the GPU memory is to be blamed, although I never had such problems in Theano. Interestingly, the ECC log of the affected GPUs shows a varying number of memory errors, ranging from zero to 500 bits. At this point I am bit lost as to how to further analyse and debug this problem. In particular, if the memory of the GPUs is faulty, then I'd need harder proof in order to ask for a replacement from my supplier.

Comment: you could test GPU memory by multiplying huge matrices with known result. IE, if A is an nxn matrix filled with 1., A*A should be an nxn matrix filled with n's

Comment: This question seems to be about the testing of hardware and secondarily about issues with Tensorflow, which is not a programming tool. It therefore appears off-topic. I would suggest highlighting the programming question that may be hidden in here.

Comment: @njuffa : the problem is: it is not entirely clear to me whether this is a problem with tensorflow or with the hardware as I cannot reproduce this bug with other packages (like Theano). So, at least partially this is a problem of the interplay between tensorflow and GPU memory.

Comment: @user45893 I've also been experiancing different (incorrect) results when using my GPU... I potted the loss using tensorboard and this confirms that it's not getting better as expected. I looked at the graph and although I'm new to this it looks like the GPU isn't actually doing all the calculations just the initialization actually.